# Returning other columns of aggregate result

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given:

```
timestamp |  col1  |   col2
============================
xx            abc      5
yy            abc      4
zz            def      7
rr            def      6


SELECT timestamp,col1,min(col2) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY col1 
ORDER BY min(col2) ASC
```

returns:

```
xx       abc     4
zz       def     6
```

timestamp seems to be messed up, so I am sure I am not using group by the way it is supposed to. How do I get:

```
yy     abc      4
rr     def      6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For guaranteed behaviour you must either have the timestamp field in an aggregate expression or in the GROUP BY clause.  If you don't (as in your example), the returned value is indeterminent (and effectively almost randomly chosen).

Instead, you can do this in two steps, and so never have any field 'randonly' chosen...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT col1, MAX(col2) as max_col2 FROM yourTable GROUP BY col1) AS lookup
    ON  yourtable.col1 = lookup.col1
    AND yourtable.col2 = lookup.col2
```

Comment: For the moment lets go with putting the timestamp field in the GROUP BY clause. That doesn't seem to work either. It produces a lot more rows than just the two I am looking for?

Comment: To clarify a bit, I have no problems with your SQL. Its just that in my case I have a poor man's SQL generator and for the moment, its not built to generate complicated queries like that.

Comment: @Dilip - Unfortunately, you need an aggregate to establish `MAX(col2)` when GROUPing BY `col1`.  Doing so, however, groups all of the timestamps together.  This means that you need a second query to go back and lookup what timestamp is assocaiated with the values you've found.  There is no single operator in MySQL that can chose a value from one group based on it being associated with the max value of another group.